# Django forms - dictionary and lists

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have created a django form having following fields:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required=True)
    type = forms.CharField(required=True)
    username = forms.CharField(required=True)
    password = forms.CharField(required=True)
```

Now when I do a cleaned data in my view:

```
form = MyForm(request.REQUEST)
data = form.cleaned_data
```

The data is a dictionary with each of the form fields. For eg.

```
data = {
   "name": "ABC",
   "type": "Testing",
   "username":"abc",
   "password":"abc"
}
```

I want that some of the fields are part of the dictionary inside the main data dictionary. For eg.

```
data = {
   "name": "ABC",
   "type": "Testing",
   "user": {
       "username":"abc",
       "password":"abc"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `form.cleaned_data` dictionary is flat. You can take that and create whatever data structure you want.

```
cleaned_data = form.cleaned_data
nested_data = {
    'name': cleaned_data['name'],
    ...
    'user': {
        'username': cleaned_data['username'],
        'password': cleaned_data['password'],
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a django way to group those fields and nest while getting cleaned data itself?

Comment: No. The dictionary returned is flat. You could try overriding methods of the form to change the format of `cleaned_data`, but I don't think that would be a good idea.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help.